# search and extract data from string base on string value

Tags: python, string

I did an OCR of a receipt and have extracted the receipt into a string.
Now, I need to extract the total amount paid from the string below ($43.43).
Is there any way to do it?

I tried using split(' ') but is not working as expected.

```
THE FOOD CLUB
78990 SOUTH STREET AVE
ALBANY, NYC, 343434

08/11/2020 05:43 PM
CHECK: 307859 CUST: 59
1 CHICKEN MEALS $9.99
EXTRA SPYCIES $0.00
2 PIDIA $25.98
Subtotal $39.57
Tax $3.86
Total $43.43
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `re.findall` here:

```py
inp = """THE FOOD CLUB
78990 SOUTH STREET AVE
ALBANY, NYC, 343434

08/11/2020 05:43 PM
CHECK: 307859 CUST: 59
1 CHICKEN MEALS $9.99
EXTRA SPYCIES $0.00
2 PIDIA $25.98
Subtotal $39.57
Tax $3.86
Total $43.43"""

total = re.findall(r'\bTotal (\$\d+(?:\.\d+)?)', inp)[0]
print(total)  # $43.43
```